# In nightwatch, how do I specify additional string arguments after the selenium_port

Tags: nightwatch.js, saucelabs

came across a similar question here which wasn't truly addressed - https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/1911

You cannot do what @beatfactor suggested with the above example, the port is in the middle i.e. "selenium_host" : "us1.appium.testobject.com:443/wd/hub",

I'm facing a similar problem right now, how do I provide arguments so it attempts to hit a host like the above?  Currently, my failing options are providing no port which defaults to 4444 or providing a port which results in attempting to hit us1.appium.testobject.com/wd/hub:443

The desired result is : 
"selenium_host" : "us1.appium.testobject.com:443/wd/hub",

TLDR - How do you provide a port in the middle of your selenium host argument given the port is always appended to the end and if you don't provide one, a default is used?

Answer (score 0):

Just define your `selenium_port` upstream, in the declaration section and use a [Template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
const selenium_port = '443';

"test_settings" : {
  "default" : {
  "launch_url" : "http://test.com",
  "selenium_port" : selenium_port 
  "selenium_host" : `us1.appium.testobject.com:${selenium_port}/wd/hub`,
  "silent" : true,
  "screenshots" : {
  "enabled" : true,
  "path" : "screenshots"
  }
},
```

Hope I understood correctly. Cheers!